# Single quote appears after YAML dump

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a problem that I wish to prevent single quote appearing in my YAML file. Is there anyway I can achieve the intended output where the goal is displayed without the single quote?

I have following code that I run in Python to update the file: (The format checking of the input is not implemented as this is a practice I'm doing to learn)

```
import sys
import yaml
import ruamel.yaml

def updateInformation():
    agentName = input("What is the name of agent you want to update?")
    endGoal = input("What is the new coordinate you want to update, type in terms of [x, y] where x and y are numbers")
    updateInputFile(agentName, endGoal)

def updateInputFile(agentName, endGoal):
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    i = 0
    with open('input.yaml') as f:
        doc = yaml.load(f)
    print(doc)
    for v in doc:
        if i < len(doc[v]):
            if doc['agents'][i]['name'] != agentName:
                i = i + 1
                pass
            else:
                if doc['agents'][i]['name'] == agentName:
                    doc['agents'][i].update({'goal': endGoal})
                    break

    yaml.representer.ignore_aliases = lambda *data: True
    with open('input.yaml', 'w') as f:
        yaml.dump(doc, f)
```

Currently the output file after the following code has been executed:

```
agents:
- start: [0, 0]
  goal: '[3, 1]'
  name: agent0
- start: [2, 0]
  goal: [0, 0]
  name: agent1
map:
  dimensions: [3, 3]
  obstacles:
  - !!python/tuple [0, 1]
  - !!python/tuple [2, 1]
```

Intended output:

```
agents:
- start: [0, 0]
  goal: [3, 1]
  name: agent0
- start: [2, 0]
  goal: [0, 0]
  name: agent1
map:
  dimensions: [3, 3]
  obstacles:
  - !!python/tuple [0, 1]
  - !!python/tuple [2, 1]
```

I'm thinking that it could be the possibility when it is being dumped back to YAML file, the value of endGoal faces an ambiguous interpretation as a string that results it being single quoted in the YAML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`endGoal` is a string right after you input it.

Try making it into a `list` of `int` before updating the YAML:

```
endGoal = '[1,2]' # for example
endGoal = [int(a_string) for a_string in endGoal.strip('[]').split(',')]
```

Comment: after updating in YAML file, it seems like the output is not what I intended to be in the YAML file:
  
  `goal:
  - !!set
    1: null
    3: null`
  
I require the file to be kept as the intended output as above, this is for when I'm loading the YAML file to be read on another python file.

Comment: After some trying, I finally understood what you meant by it. Thanks for the answer! I managed to get the intended output through your method!